# Jboss Server Not Loading Java Environment Properties

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, system, getproperty

I am trying to load a properties file in a web application using the following code in Java.

```
InputStream in = ContextEventListener.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceConstVal);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.load(in);
```

When this application runs on tomcat server; all the properties specified in the properties file get exported as system variables and are accessible via the following code

```
System.getProperty("TEMP")
```

` 
However, when the same application ran on Jboss server; the properties had to be explicitly exported by

```
Set<Object> keySet = config.keySet();
for (Iterator iterator = keySet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
String strVal = (String) iterator.next();
System.setProperty(strVal, config.getProperty(strVal));
}
```

Using JDK 1.6 , Tomcat 7.0 , Jboss AS 6.1.

Content of Property File
CONTENT_DIR=XXXXXX
RESPONSE_FILE_NM=YYYYYYYY
REQUEST_INT_FILE_NM=ZZZZZZZ

Wondering why behavior varies in different application server.

Answer (score 0):

That's becouse Jboss puts the .properties file inside jars on the classpath and can not be edited sometime after the deploy. Here is a workaround https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath

Comment: To load properties file, it only needs read permission which is present because the Properties object loads fine from input stream. It's the individual properties that are not exported.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken.

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-18247